# Joining tables with same key variable but with different number of records

Tags: sql, join

I need to join two tables with the same ID value but different number of records.
Here is what I have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my syntax:

```
select  a.id,
    a.event_a,
    a.occur_a,
    a.site_a,
    b.event_b,
    b.site_b

from table_1 a

full outer join table_2 b

on a.id=b.id;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an independent ordering for most of the columns in the two tables.

This should do what you want:

```
select  a.id, a.event_a, a.occur_a, a.site_a,
        b.event_b, b.site_b
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table_1 a
     ) a full outer join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table_2 b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id;
```